# Filter field "to" contains word

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'd like to make filter like: `to:*spam*@domain.com`. It was possible couple years ago. But now there is [another story](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6593):

> Gmail doesn't recognize special search characters like [ ], ( ), &, #, *, and currency symbols.

I've unique address for each service that I use (microsoft_spam@, spam_google@, all_spam_dropbox@, etc). And I want store all mail from set of services in one folder (filter).

Is there any way to do it, without creating separated filter for each service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid wildcards don't work. You need to use the `OR` operator.

So, something like:

```
spam@dropbox.com OR spam@google.com OR spam@microsoft.com
```

In the "To:" field in the advanced search.

Your filter will end up looking like:

```
to:(spam@dropbox.com OR spam@google.com OR spam@microsoft.com)
```

You *might* be able to do this: Just use the keyword you want in the "To:" field, not an entire email address.

```
to:(spam OR phishing)
```